# Problem with using Fiona to write out GeoJSON objects to GeoPackage layers

Tags: python, geojson, geopackage, fiona

I'm attempting to use `fiona` to write out a number of GeoJSON objects to different layers in a single GeoPackage.

Here's an example `json.dumps()` representation of the GeoJSON object containing one feature:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
    {"type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [[bunch of coord pairs]]},
     "properties": {
         "dataType": "Shapefile",
         "fname": "cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",
         "path": "file:///C:\\Data\\Foundation\\US\\cb_2018_us_state_500k",
         "native_crs": 4269,
         "lastmod": "2019-04-15T15:55:28"}
}]}
```

This feature collection, call it `feature_collection_a`, is stashed as one of many, sharing the same schema, in a `dict` I'm iterating over to write the outputs:

```
layers = {'level_00': feature_collection_a,
          'level_01': feature_collection_b}
```

So I try to do (assuming I've imported `from_epsg` from `fiona.crs`):

```
path = 'C:/path/to/someoutput.gpkg'
driver = 'GPKG'
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon',
          'properties': OrderedDict([
              ('dataType', 'str'),
              ('fname', 'str'),
              ('path', 'str'),
              ('native_crs', 'int'),
              ('lastmod', 'str')])}

for k, v in layers.items():
    if v:
        with fiona.open(path, 'w',
                        schema=schema,
                        driver=driver,
                        crs=from_epsg(4326),
                        layer=k) as outlayer:
            outlayer.write(v)
```

This gives me:

```
Record does not match collection schema: dict_keys([]) != ['path', 'fname', 'dataType', 'native_crs', 'lastmod']
```

Since I am using an `OrderedDict()` to construct both the `properties` element (in the raw geojson object represented by `v`) and in `schema`, I am confused as to why this is failing.

When I try it with `geopandas` it works fine:

```
import geopandas as gpd

for k, v in layers.items():
    if v:
        gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(v)
        gdf.crs = 'EPSG:4326'
        gdf.to_file(path, driver=driver, layer=k)
```

And since `geopandas` uses `fiona` for its r/w ops, it tells me the problem is not with `fiona` but with how I'm (mis)using it.

I could just use `geopandas` to do this, but (A) I feel like that's lazy and (B) relying on a very high level package like GeoPandas makes my script more fragile than I'd like.

Comment: @nmtoken what makes you think that this applies here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`writerecords`](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fiona.html#fiona.collection.Collection.writerecords) method (it takes a list of Features) instead of the `write` methods (which takes a FeatureCollection) and it appears to works :

```py
for k, v in layers.items():
    if v:
        with fiona.open(path, 'w',
                        schema=schema,
                        driver=driver,
                        crs=from_epsg(4326),
                        layer=k) as outlayer:
            outlayer.writerecords(v['features']) # <- changed this line
```

Using the `writerecords` methods also seems to be what is done internally by geopandas (here in [`file.py`](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/63de9bd1820080eedc443c09df7686e1022304a0/geopandas/io/file.py#L294))

However I don't know why it doesn't work as expected with `write`.

Comment: Interesting, that works.  I'll mark this as correct but I'm also a bit confused... maybe I'll create an issue at the repo on this.